# CSS transition when clicking on button - CodePen example

Tags: html, css, codepen

I have a button that adds a image above a presentbox. It is 2 frames - the presentbox, and the image above it when the button is pressed.

The image just "pops" above the the box. I want the image (in this case, the truck) to smoothly transition from the presentbox and a bit up from the box/the same position the truck have now. How can I do it?

Codepen with a simple example:

https://codepen.io/Arte_2/pen/dyOLYwN

```
      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("truck").innerHTML = `
    <img    src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e0/8b/14/e08b1415885d4d2ddd7fd3f75967da29.png"></img>`
        console.log(this.show)
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id ="truck"></div>
  <img class="box" src="https://img.pngio.com/png-file-svg-box-icon-vector-png-transparent-cartoon-free-box-icon-png-920_852.png" on-click="handleClick"></img>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
        }

        .circle {
          height: 36px;
          width: 36px;
          border-radius: 50%;
          visibility: visible;
          background-color: var(green);

          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }

        .icon {
          height: 26px;
          width: 26px;
          line-height: 0;
        }

        .header-text {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          margin-left: 14px;
          height: 48px;
        }

        .container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 100%;
        }

       img {
          height: 240px;
          width: 250px;
          flex-grow: 0;
        }

        .box {
          width: 350px;
          height: 350px;
        }
```

Comment: You are simply adding the `<img>` to the `<div>` onclick, this won't give you the intended effect. One way to do this would to add the `<div><img>` to the body, add `transition: all 1s` to smoothing between frames, and use CSS to hide the image using `opacity: 0` or `position: absolute, left: -100px`. Then onclick, undo your "hiding" method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not editing any CSS property. You are just creating a new element with JavaScript.

You have two options: create the element and animate it with javascript or, a simpler one, to have the element in the page and animate its height, for example, to make it appears. Here is your code where toggling a class to the truck div and it appears or disappears depending on its classList:

```
<head>
  <link rel="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="truck"><img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e0/8b/14/e08b1415885d4d2ddd7fd3f75967da29.png" class=""></img></div>
  <img class="box" src="https://img.pngio.com/png-file-svg-box-icon-vector-png-transparent-cartoon-free-box-icon-png-920_852.png" on-click="handleClick"></img>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("truck").classList.toggle("visible");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>


#truck {
  height: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#truck.visible {
  height: 280px;
}
```